# automatically sliding using JavaScript, trying to make the slider slide without any clicking

Tags: javascript, slider

1. So the following code makes the slider slide on click but l want to implement automatic slider can someone help me so that l don't need to click but it can slide on it's own. So l want to implement automatic javascript slider using the following code

   ```
           <input class="slide" type="radio" name="slider-1" id="s-1-1" /><label for="s-1-1"></label>
           <div>
               <img src="images\slide01.jpg" style="height: 110%" />
               <div class="content">
                   <h3>Bluhh Bluhh Bluhh</h3>
                   <p>bluuhh bluhh bluhh bluhh bluuhh bluhh bluhh bluhh bluuhh bluhh bluhh bluhh bluuhh bluhh bluhh
                       bluhh bluuhh bluhh bluhh bluhh</p>
                   <a href="#" class="button button-blue">Get Started</a>
               </div>
           </div>

           <input class="slide" type="radio" name="slider-1" id="s-1-2" /><label for="s-1-2"></label>
           <div>
               <img src="images\slide02.jpg" style="height: 110%" />
               <div class="content">
                   <h3>Bluhh Bluhh Bluhh</h3>
                   <p>bluuhh bluhh bluhh bluhh bluuhh bluhh bluhh bluhh bluuhh bluhh bluhh bluhh bluuhh bluhh bluhh
                       bluhh bluuhh bluhh bluhh bluhh</p>
                   <a href="#" class="button button-orange">Integrate Now</a>
               </div>
           </div>

           <input class="slide" type="radio" name="slider-1" id="s-1-3" /><label for="s-1-3"></label>
           <div>
               <img src="images\slide03.jpg" style="height: 110%" />
               <div class="content">
                   <h3>Bluhh Bluhh Bluhh</h3>
                   <p>bluuhh bluhh bluhh bluhh bluuhh bluhh bluhh bluhh bluuhh bluhh bluhh bluhh bluuhh bluhh bluhh
                       bluhh bluuhh bluhh bluhh bluhh</p>
                   <a href="#" class="button button-orange">Integrate Now</a>
               </div>
           </div>

           <input class="slide" type="radio" name="slider-1" id="s-1-4" /><label for="s-1-4"></label>
           <div>
               <img src="images\slide04.jpg" style="height: 110%" />
               <div class="content">
                   <h3>Bluhh Bluhh Bluhh</h3>
                   <p>bluuhh bluhh bluhh bluhh bluuhh bluhh bluhh bluhh bluuhh bluhh bluhh bluhh bluuhh bluhh bluhh
                       bluhh bluuhh bluhh bluhh bluhh</p>
                   <a href="#" class="button button-orange">Integrate Now</a>
               </div>
           </div>

           <input class="slide" type="radio" name="slider-1" id="s-1-5" /><label for="s-1-5"></label>
           <div>
               <img src="images\slide05.jpg" style="height: 110%" />
               <div class="content">
                   <h3>Bluhh Bluhh Bluhh</h3>
                   <p>bluuhh bluhh bluhh bluhh bluuhh bluhh bluhh bluhh bluuhh bluhh bluhh bluhh bluuhh bluhh bluhh
                       bluhh bluuhh bluhh bluhh bluhh</p>
                   <a href="#" class="button button-orange">Integrate Now</a>
               </div>
           </div>

           <input class="slide" type="radio" name="slider-1" id="s-1-6" checked /><label for="s-1-6"></label>
           <div>
               <img src="images\slide06.jpg" style="height: 120%" />
               <div class="content">
                   <h3>Bluhh Bluhh Bluhh</h3>
                   <p>bluuhh bluhh bluhh bluhh bluuhh bluhh bluhh bluhh bluuhh bluhh bluhh bluhh bluuhh bluhh bluhh
                       bluhh bluuhh bluhh bluhh bluhh</p>
                   <a href="#" class="button button">Publish Now</a>
               </div>
           </div>
   ```

   function doSlide(slider) {
               var id, o = slider.querySelectorAll("input.slide"),
                   last = o.length - 1,
                   current = slider.querySelector("input.slide:checked");
               for (var i = 0; i < o.length; i++)
                   if (o[i] === current) {
                       id = i;
                       break;
                   }
               o[id >= last ? 0 : id + 1].click();
           }

   ```
       function onSlide(e) {
           var o = e.target.parentNode;
           clearTimeout(o.autoslider);
           o.autoslider = setTimeout(function() {
               doSlide(o);
           }, 7e3);
       }
       $(function() {
           $(document).on("click", "input.slide", onSlide);
           $(".slider").each(function() {
               doSlide(this)
           });
       });
   </script>
   ```

Comment: Here a way to do this using only CSS (https://codepen.io/zackw/pen/FcIaq).
If you want a help using javascript comment a JSFiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/) with your js, html and css. Through this I can help you.

Comment: thank you @DanrleyWillyan l did the CSS one